# Not able to setup Hierarchical partition keys on the portal of Azure Cosmos db emulator

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

Has anybody been able to setup hierarchical partition keys on Azure cosmos db emulator. I tried following this post from Microsoft -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys?tabs=net-v3%2Cbicep

This is what I have done so far -

1. Uninstalled and installed latest version of the emulator.
2. Started the emulator from the installation directory and ran this command in powershell - .\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe /EnablePreview

I didn't find the option to setup Hierarchical partition keys.

Screenshot of the New Container creation screen -

[image]

Comment: Looks like you enabled hierarchical partition keys via command line (the Preview flag). Now please edit to show your code for setting up a container with hierarchical partition key.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have added the screenshot of the new container creation screen.

Answer (score 3):

I just downloaded the latest version of the Emulator and started it with the `/EnablePreview` flag.

Unfortunately the last time the bundled Data Explorer was updated was May 2022 according to [the release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-release-notes) - which predates this feature being added to the [data explorer code base](https://github.com/Azure/cosmos-explorer/commit/701f486d8ffc0c16ab32c4a15ae59afc56d2888c).

But the back end stuff appears to work fine.

Creating a collection with hierarchical partition key works fine if you connect to it and [do it programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys?tabs=net-v3%2Cbicep#sdk).

e.g. Using the following code based on the examples in the docs did work

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;

//well known Emulator connection string
using CosmosClient client = new(
    "https://localhost:8081",
    "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");

;
await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("soquestion");
var database = client.GetDatabase("soquestion");

List<string> subpartitionKeyPaths = new List<string> {
    "/TenantId",
    "/UserId",
    "/SessionId"
};

// Create a container properties object
ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(
    id: "hierPKTest",
    partitionKeyPaths: subpartitionKeyPaths
);

// Create a container that's subpartitioned by TenantId > UserId > SessionId
Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerProperties, throughput: 400);

var item = new 
{
    id = "f7da01b0-090b-41d2-8416-dacae09fbb4a",
    TenantId = "Microsoft",
    UserId = "8411f20f-be3e-416a-a3e7-dcd5a3c1f28b",
    SessionId = "0000-11-0000-1111"
};

// Specify the full partition key path when creating the item
PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKeyBuilder()
    .Add(item.TenantId)
    .Add(item.UserId)
    .Add(item.SessionId)
    .Build();

// Create the item in the container
var createResponse = await container.CreateItemAsync(item, partitionKey);

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

At the time of giving this answer interacting with these documents via data explorer was not possible and gave an error.

[image]

As of the latest version (2.14.16) I can now edit these documents in the bundled  data explorer. I still don't see any UI support for creating collections with hierarchical partition keys in this though so probably this still needs to be done through code.